# HighCharts not displaying all the categories

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm using HighCharts library for displaying charts for my project. I've modified the chart a bit. I have kind of combined these two charts http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes and http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-rotated-labels together to get the desired chart. But the problem now is that when the charts are displayed. All the categories are not displayed and only the first

Comment: Try removing type: category. what is your chart_data ?? can you post that data here. z

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have several series, each with only one data point.  That will, by default, only show one category, because it is grouping them (the first point of each series in the first category, the second point of each series in the second category, etc).

I would suggest making this one series - it is overkill and adds unnecessary complications to make each data point a series.

Alternatively, if you're stuck to the idea of multiple series, you can add `grouping: false` to your plotOptions, which will over ride the default behavior.

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.grouping

**UPDATE:**

I forgot to add that you need to include an x value for each data point as well.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/101/

Comment: Setting grouping:false doesn't help. And I have to make it all different series. Because the problem is that the three data one is very huge in millions and other are in hundreds. So their graph is not even visible. I have to make them visible. Giving them different axis. So that graph is drawn respective to their own values.

Comment: See updated answer.  However, by using different series, and plotting the points on different axes, you have completely negated the entire point of plotting columns on the same chart - comparing them.  If the length of the bar doesn't encode the value relative to the other bars, you completely mislead the viewer and misrepresent the data.  FWIW

Comment: Thank you for helping me. And yes you are right about misleading the viewer. But that's what I am asked to do. So is there anyway around this? The jsfiddle you provided in that even if I give some data very huge values and some very less the chart for the lower values still doesn't show. Is there anyway I can show them.

Comment: I have to hide the 0 values when I use the dataLabels.

Comment: @AkashKumar What's with setting an x value per point, as jlbriggs already explained ? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/73oq2nzc/4/